# How to check if TimeSpan.ParseExact is true or not

Tags: c#, timespan

I want to check the correct format of a time span string

```
intervalString = "23:54:00";
format = "hh\\:mm\\:ss";
culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

var reded= TimeSpan.ParseExact(intervalString, "hh\\:mm\\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The result is `23:54:00`

If I try with `intervalString = "28:54:00";` I get an exception.
How can I check if it failed and continue my code without exception?

Comment: Use `TryParseExact` - it's designed for precisely that purpose.

Comment: (It's not clear why you've tagged this with wpf by the way - it's really not WPF-specific.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `TimeSpan.TryParseExact()` instead. It will return a `bool` value that indicates if the value was parsed successfully.

```
TimeSpan reded;

bool success = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(intervalString, "hh\\:mm\\:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out reded);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) designed for this particular case:

```
var isParsed = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(
    intervalString, 
    "hh\\:mm\\:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    out TimeSpan reded      // it's your parsed value
);

// use reded if isParsed == true
```